# можно ли использовать несколько версий пхп на убунту без докера?

Tags: ubuntu

можно ли использовать несколько версий пхп на убунту без докера? Если да то как

Comment: Можно, установив интересующие пакеты интересующих версий например из какого-нибудь ppa https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php

Comment: просто установить и использовать. уточните, что именно у вас не получается, прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]